# flask session - TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, authentication, flask, session

I'm trying to verify a user using flask session. The problem is that whenever I try to assign a value to my session, I get the error:

> TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment

I have seen [This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61804039/typeerror-session-object-does-not-support-item-assignment) and I have been using guides such as [this one](https://www.educba.com/flask-session/), however I have been unable to solve this problem.

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from flask_session import Session
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form['un']
    password = request.form['pw']
    Session['name'] = request.form['un'] #this is where my error is occuring
else:
    username = request.args.get('un')
    password = request.args.get('pw')
    Session["name"] = request.args.get('un')
```

I thought that my error could have been related to `request.form['un']`, so I changed the code to:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from flask_session import Session
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form['un']
    password = request.form['pw']
    Session['test'] = 'test' #still have an error here
else:
    username = request.args.get('un')
    password = request.args.get('pw')
    Session["test"] = "test"
```

App is setup like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = True
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.secret_key = 'why would I tell you my secret key?'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)
```

If this is something silly then I apologize for wasting your time :). I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign the value to Session object.

If you check the example on the [project's repo](https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session/blob/master/examples/hello.py), you'll see it assigns the value to [flask session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.session), not flask_session's Session object:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session


SESSION_TYPE = 'redis'


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)


@app.route('/set/')
def set():
    # check here
    # it is flask's session, not flask_session's Session object
    session['key'] = 'value'
    return 'ok'


@app.route('/get/')
def get():
    return session.get('key', 'not set')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, had an issue with redis but code works without it. :)